# Moving SQLite-D7 Installation to other Server throws Uncaught exception in shutdown function

Tags: 7, database

When I move my Drupal7-Website (with SQLite Database) from my XAMP to another Computer also running XAMP I got the following error message.

> Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a
>   readonly database: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => 192200923514edf6a15a484.46864520 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myd7site/includes/lock.inc).

How comes? And how to fix?
Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the PDO SQLite driver requires that if you are going to do a write operation (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,DROP, etc), then the folder the database resides in must have write permissions, as well as the actual database file.

The above information is taken from another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330616/2171489

I don't use SQLite, but given the error from the PDO driver and the fact that you moved to a different server, it does seem like it could be a file permission problem.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to database bin folder in xamp (xampp\mysql\bin)
2. Open my.ini
3. Change value of `"max_allowed_packet"` to "256m" (or larger)
4. Save my.ini Now restart MySql through the XAMPP control panel.

Comment: Thanx. But as I mentioned in the Question I don't use mySQL. I use SQLite. So no mySQL-Server is running.

Comment: (xampp\mysql\bin) written as example. "Go to database bin folder in xamp". find your using db server's `.ini` and change value

Comment: sorry, can't find any sqlite database bin folder.

Comment: solution is that, u need to increase `max_allowed_packet` value. find it and do.

Comment: yes, shure I understand that. but I don't find this string for sqlite. I only find this string for mysql-solution.

Comment: find some equilant for this

Comment: funny one, hm...?